# Comparing the sum of two numbers in x86 assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I am trying to run a trivial program that I wrote in x86 AT&T assembler but I seem to be getting a result that seems strange to me - clearly I am doing something wrong.

```
/*
 Take two integer numbers, get the sum and check if they are equal.
 If they are equal, print so, if not, exit silently.
 */

.data

num1: .byte 100
num2: .byte 50
sum:  .byte 150
msg:  .string "Sum is correct"

.text

.globl main
main:
    /* compute sum */
    mov $num1, %eax
    add $num2, %eax
    /* compare and jump */
    cmp $sum, %eax
    jne finish
    /* print message */
    mov $msg, %edi
    call puts
finish:
    ret
```

The above program compiles just fine with `gcc` under Linux but it acts as if the numbers are not equal and thus doesn't print anything.

I have tried the same code but commenting out the jump and it shows the text so for some reason the `cmp` is not giving me the right result. I also tried changing `eax` to `al` and `.byte` to `.long` in case of a size issue to no avail.

I haven't taught myself how to debug or set breakpoints yet so I'm relying on the output to make my assumptions.

How can I get this to output correctly?

Comment: `cmp $sum, %eax` compares against the address, just like you're using the address of the other variables because you used a `$`.  You want `cmp sum, %al` to compare 1 byte from memory.  Or better, make `sum` an assemble-time constant instead of storing it in data memory, so you can usefully use it as an immediate.

Comment: You want to load from memory. Remove the `$` signs in the first three instructions as those mean immediate in at&t syntax. You were operating on the addresses. Also you have bytes so switch to `%al`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Wow, thankyou very much! Works a charm. May I ask how I can create an assemble-time constant? I've seen NASM examples but AT&T seems to be sorely lacking. (from my basic understanding) Maybe you could write an answer?

Comment: *I haven't taught myself how to debug or set breakpoints yet so I'm relying on the output to make my assumptions.* - Fix that problem first; you're wasting your time (and everyone else's) if you can't / don't use a debugger to look at register contents and single-step.  In GDB, `start` or `starti` and then `stepi` (aka `si`).  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Asm is very hard to debug from just output, and but more easy than most languages to debug with a debugger.

Comment: @Jester Thankyou. Is there a particular reason why I cannot still use `eax` with a byte? Would it not be loaded it into the lowest byte automatically?

Comment: Assemble-time constant: `.equ sum, 150`.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/

Comment: You can only load a byte into EAX with `movzbl sum, %eax` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx).  or `movsbl` to sign-extend.  Other instructions require both their operands to be the same size.  So `mov sum, %eax` would load 4 bytes, including 3 bytes from the string that comes after.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the links Peter. I use valgrind in C but given I can look at the registers I'll be using GDB too now.